# Error related to deployment of Angular to server

Tags: angular, deployment, server, hosting, shared

I have an angular application which i have uploaded to server(This is the first time I am uploading it to server.)I am getting some kind of error in the console which i am not able to solve.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU5Lh.png)(Console error image) can i have the steps to deploy angular apps to server .I have shared hosting: Fast Comet and my backend is Flask(python) and angular app to slow to load

Comment: locally your app works just fine ? no errors ?

Comment: yes..it works fine.. when i generate the file using ng build  command  and gets dist folder and i upload it